# crop image height without scaling

Tags: css

I know this is a easy question but i just can't seem to find the solution.

I am currently using a bootstrap carousel, with 1920x1080 res images.
I want the image to stay the same, but the height to be cropped down to 480px.
Note. NO SCALING.... the image should just be cut-off, no stretching or scaling.

lets say this is my css class:

```
.carousel-top-img{
    height: 480px;// image scaled down to 853x480px
}
```

---

```
.carousel-top-img{
    max-height: 480px;// image stretched but 1920x480px met
    width: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't use bootstrap, but here's a pure CSS solution:

```
#this_img{
        width: 1920px;
        height: 480px;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

A bit more on **object-fit**: [LINK](https://css-tricks.com/on-object-fit-and-object-position/)

I hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, it appears Bootstrap has a `height: auto;` clause on it's `.carousel-inner>.item>img` which was interfering with me when I tried this before...

Comment: Tip for people doing this: if you find that the visible part of the cropped image is the wrong end of it (e.g., it shows the bottom of the cropped image and you want to see the top), add an `object-position` CSS property together with the `object-fit`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the dimensions of `.carousel-top-img`'s **container** and apply `overflow: hidden` to it.